# как сверстать такой блок с изгибами?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю как сверстать такой блок с бордером и обходом цифры с изгибами. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#main {
    margin: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main .edge {
    position: absolute;
}

#main .edge.top {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#main .edge.left {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#main .corner {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#main .corner-2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.head {
  max-width: calc(100% - 90px);
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.desc {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="edge top"></div>
  <div class="edge left"></div>
  <div class="corner"></div>
  <div class="corner-2">3</div>
  <div class="head">
    Lorem ipsum dolor
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est in eum expedita repellendus ipsam saepe incidunt mollitia! Iusto totam obcaecati, nesciunt impedit, ducimus ullam minima provident, nulla magni illo adipisci.
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    margin: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .edge {
    position: absolute;
}

.wrapper .edge.top {
  top: 0;
  left: 16px;
  right: 67px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .edge.left {
  left: 0;
  top: 16px;
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .edge.right {
  left: 10px;
  top: 64px;
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .edge.bottom {
  left: 16px;
  top: 64px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .edge.top-2 {
  left: 16px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .corner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 17px;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 2;
}

.wrapper .corner-2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 3;
}

.head {
  max-width: calc(100% - 90px);
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.desc {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.wrapper::before {
    left: 0;
}
.wrapper::before, .wrapper::after {
    top: 0;
}
.wrapper::after {
    right: 50px;
}
.content::before {
    left: 0;
}
.content::after {
    right: 0;
}
.content::before, .content::after {
    bottom: 0;
}
.corner-3 {
  right: 0;
  top: 49px;
}
.wrapper::before, .wrapper::after, .content::before, .content::after, .corner-3 {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="edge top"></div>
      <div class="edge top-2"></div>
      <div class="edge left"></div>
      <div class="edge right"></div>
      <div class="edge bottom"></div>
      <div class="corner"></div>
      <div class="corner-2">3</div>
      <div class="corner-3"></div>
      <div class="head">
        Lorem ipsum dolor
      </div>
      <div class="desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est in eum expedita repellendus ipsam saepe incidunt mollitia! Iusto totam obcaecati, nesciunt impedit, ducimus ullam minima provident, nulla magni illo adipisci.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: я примерно так и сделал. Но опять же, изгибов то нет)

Comment: дополнил ответ с изгибами

Answer (score 1):

```html
<body>
    <style>
        .box {
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px dashed #aaa;
        }

        svg {
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        }
    </style>
    <div class = "box">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 694 284" fill="none">
        <path d="M672.182 283H20C9.5066 283 1 274.493 1 264V20C1 9.50659 9.50659 1 20 1H552C562.493 1 571 9.50659 571 20V100C571 111.598 580.402 121 592 121H673.316C683.878 121 692.412 129.613 692.315 140.174L691.181 264.174C691.086 274.599 682.608 283 672.182 283Z" stroke="#C0D9E7" stroke-width="2"/>
        <rect x="591" width="103" height="100" rx="20" fill="#CC2D46"/>
    </svg>    
    </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: SVG - это отличное решение, но как обстоят дела с адаптивностью и масштабом (допустим, если высота должна зависеть от количества текста)?

Comment: @UModeL, так же как и с другими элементами?

Comment: как же текст растянет фиксированные абсолютные размеры?

Comment: @UModeL а что мешает сделать их не фиксированными?

Comment: Вопрос в чем? "Не понимаю как сверстать такой блок с бордером и обходом цифры с изгибами. Подскажите пожалуйста" Верстать на html + css это мутор и костыль. Я показал пример. Не устраивает? Ставь минус.

Comment: тоже не оч понимаю как его использовать с текстом